# Four Directions #18 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

To the North, Jorge and Natan spent some quality time
To the South, a victory for a famous symbol
To the West, you can check out one of Baird's
To the East is a presidential coastal town

A Nereid carried a man to me long ago to explore the depths of my mind

Where and what am I?

Comment: I realized the East clue needed a slight adjustment - apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> the Great Blue Hole in Belize.

To the North, Jorge and Natan spent some quality time

> Banco Chinchorro (from Tahel)

To the South, a victory for a famous symbol

> ?

To the West, you can check out one of Baird's

> Reserva de Biosfera Maya, a Guatemalan natural reserve where you can spot a Baird's tapir.

To the East is a presidential coastal town

> ?

A Nereid carried a man to me long ago to explore the depths of my mind

> Calypso was a Nereid in Greek mythology, and RV *Calypso* was the ship of Jacques Cousteau who explored the Great Blue Hole in 1971.

Comment: This is correct!  For West, I was looking at rot13(oryvmr mbb), for East, rot13(n fznyy gbja ba gur jrfg pbnfg bs Wnznvpn) and for south, rot13(n fznyy gbja "bs gur pebff").

Answer (score 2):

**line 1:**

> To the North, Jorge and Natan spent some quality time

means:

> **Jorge and Natan**-These are father and son from the film "Alamar"-(To the Sea),And they spent on  Banco Chinchorro.

**line 2:**

> To the South, a victory for a famous symbol

means:

> There are two countries-El Salvador & Honduras where in 1969 there was a soccer game (which is a famous symbol) and because of the **victory** of one of the countries-El Salvador war broke out between them for 100 hours

**line 3:**

> To the West, you can check out one of Baird's

means:

> **Baird's**-Baird's tapir is a species of tapir native to Mexico.

**line 4:**

> To the East is a presidential beach

means:

> To the east are the Cayman Islands, where the "presidential beach"-**The Seven mile beach**,this beach  recently receiving the honor of "The Caribbean's Best Beach" from Caribbean Travel and Life Magazine.

**line 5:**

> A Nereid carried a man to me long ago to explore the depths of my mind

means:

> **A Nereid**-are sea nymphs (female spirits of sea waters)-a hint to the sea .**"the depths of my mind"**-This place is close to a city called "Tela", "Tela" is Latin for woven and is used to describe a web-like membrane or layer,This word is mainly known from "The tela choroidea"- is a region of meningeal pia mater and underlying ependyma that gives rise to the choroid plexus in each of the brain’s four ventricles. For more information, please see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tela_choroidea

the answer is:

> **Where am I**:in the Caribbean Sea, and **what am I**:Lighthouse Reef

Comment: You are definitely in the correct region.  North is correct.  South and East are more direct plays on words.  West is a more specific place.  The last clue may need a bit more research, unless the other four reveal the answer first.  Definitely on the right track!